# zenbook + debian 8, не инициализирует hdmi монитор

Tags: debian, видеокарта, видеодрайвера

Поставил Debian 8 на ноутбук zenbook с видеокартой intell, на самом экране жуткое разрешение в 3200px и его нельзя регулировать,  hdmi монитор не виден. В настройках, пробовал поставить grender - вместо него предложил пакет lxrender, поставил arender - не видит воторого монитора и нельзя менять разрешение

Answer (score 0):

С Debian так и не смог совладать, помимо невозможности управления разрешением монитора, еще и не работал HDMI монитор. Возможно если по шаманить, то можно все сделать как надо, но я поставил Ubuntu - все прошло гладко и отлично работает, лучше чем в Windows 10, с первого запуска масштабирование экрана устанавливается оптимальным, HDMI так же работает.